# How can I contain coefficients from the Stationary Wavelet Transform into a column of a variable?

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

I am trying to apply the stationary wavelet transform to some coefficients in a cell array, but when doing so I end up with a row of coefficients stored in the variable as opposed to a column. I have been doing something similar with the DWT where the coefficients have been contained to just a column and this has worked well, I was expecting the coefficients from the SWT to also be contained in columns, but unfortunately not. Does anyone know why this is?

Here is the function that I'm using:

[L1,H1] = swt(f{1},1,'haar');

Does anyone know how I can get the coefficients contained in a column instead of a row?

Comment: Can't you transpose? `.'`

Answer (score 0):

Use transpose operator or `reshape`.